# Rezip file without creating temporaries

Tags: linux, bash, zip, unzip

Maybe it's best I just start off with the use case.
I have a large zip file full of many files and I suspect it was originally zipped at a low compression level.

I want to create a new zip file from that one (or not new, hopefully in-place) to make sure it is compressed well (`-9`) without unzipping it to disk first (for various reasons such as size and being a mounted NFS). So while I could just do

```
mkdir tmp/ && unzip -d tmp/ A.zip && cd tmp/ && zip -r -9 ../B.zip *; rm -rf tmp/ A.zip
```

That would [temporarily] create a huge amount of data (the *unzipped files* and `B.zip` come into existence before `A.zip` is removed).
I'd really want something along the lines of:

```
rezip -9 A.zip
```

or, settling for a `B.zip`:

```
unzip -<output to stdout> A.zip | zip -9 B.zip && rm -f A.zip
```

But I realise this mightn't really be possible since the pipe would be used for multiple files and things like filenames would be lost.

So, I'm wondering whether there's a way to execute some code on each file, like `find -exec <command>`

```
unzip A.zip -exec zip -r B.zip && rm -f A.zip
```

But again, unsure how this would work or, if this isnt facilitated by `unzip`/`zip`, whether there exists a command that does.

<sub>I've included my current, still-using-temps of individual files workaround as an answer since it might help someone, albeit unaccepted since it doesn't answer the question of *no temporaries allowed*</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but here's how you do it.
Works for files with spaces in the name, and sub directories.

```
zipinfo -1 A.zip | while read filename
do
    unzip -p A.zip "$filename" | zip -9 A.zip -
    zip --delete A.zip "$filename"
    printf "@ -\n@=$filename\n" | zipnote -w A.zip
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution:

```
unzip -p original.zip | zip -9 new.zip -
```

unzip -p tells unzip to send output to stdout. The last dash of the zip command tells it to read from stdin.

You still need to rename new.zip to original.zip if you really need it.

Comment: that only works for single files compressed using the zip algorithm, not archives under zip. Try `echo bob > bob.txt; echo steve > steve.txt; zip original {bob,steve}.txt; unzip -l original.zip` it shows two files. Now, using your solution, repack `unzip -p original.zip | zip -9 new.zip -; unzip -l new.zip` only one 'file' named '-'

Answer (score 0):

The open-source [Zip-Ada](http://unzip-ada.sf.net/) project has exactly such a rezip tool.

1. get / download the sources
2. build with the command `gnatmake -P zipada` (you get GNAT through apt or yum)
3. you have now a binary rezip with the following options:

.

```
Usage: rezip [options] archive(s)[.zip]

Options:  -defl     : repack archive only with the Deflate
                    subformat (most compatible)
          -fast_dec : repack archive only with fast decompressing subformats
          -int      : use internal Zip-Ada algorithms only, no external call
          -touch    : set time stamps to now
          -lower    : set full file names to lower case
          -del_comm : delete comment
          -comp     : compare original and repacked archives (paranoid mode)
          -rs=n     : loop many times over a single compression approach
                        having randomization, and keep optimum when size is
                        stable after n attempts in a row
```

To start with, I recommend using the `-defl` and `-int` options (notably, `-defl` will keep the resulting Zip file compatible with old tools like `unzip`).

The command will be then for instance `./rezip -int -defl -comp A.zip`

Comment: looks like they have pre-compiled for windows which is excellent for them, but if you're on linux it'd be easier to just use the [standard tools](https://superuser.com/a/1094729/241800)